# Creating Subflows in PEGA PRPC 6.3

Tags: pega

I have read the handbook for Pega PRPC 6.3, How can I create subflows within the main flow? Is there any resource/tutorial that shows a step by step approach?

Also I need to add steps and parameters for a flow, how shall I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Subflows are just normal flows. You can call them from your main flow by dragging a subflow shape to your flow diagram and refer the flow you want to make as subflow.

You can visit https://pdn.pega.com for more information and resources.

To add steps to your flow, you can easily drag and drop items from the menu. To add a parameter, go to parameters tab and add your parameter name type and other info. You can pass the value for the parameter when you call the flow.